# centos7 yum-complete-transaction errors

Tags: php, centos, centos7, yum

There is caution "There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package."

I'm running **yum-complete-transaction**, it starts fine:

base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  29 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 4.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
nginx                                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00
nux-dextop                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi                                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-debuginfo                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php55-debuginfo                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php56-debuginfo                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-php72                                               | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-test                                                | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-test-debuginfo                                      | 3.0 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
(1/17): epel/x86_64/group_gz                               |  88 kB   00:00
(2/17): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                             | 956 kB   00:00
(3/17): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                             | 166 kB   00:01
(4/17): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                           | 6.0 MB   00:01

...

There are 1 outstanding transactions to complete. Finishing the most recent one

The remaining transaction had 593 elements left to run

Removing ...

Removing ...

...

--> Processing Dependency ...

...

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

**And in the end there is a error:**

---> Package gnupg1.x86_64 0:1.4.20-1.el7.remi will be erased

--> Processing Dependency: gnupg < 2 for package: php-pear-crypt-gpg-1.6.3-1.el7.remi.noarch

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

```
Error: Package: php-pear-crypt-gpg-1.6.3-1.el7.remi.noarch (remi)
           Requires: gnupg < 2
           Removing: gnupg1-1.4.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               gnupg = 1.4.20-1.el7.remi
           Removing: gnupg2-2.0.22-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               gnupg = 2.0.22-4.el7
           Updated By: gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64 (base)
               gnupg = 2.0.22-5.el7_5
```

I removed all that has "php" in its name, but error didn't disappear.
Then I tried to find this "php-pear-crypt-gpg":

```
find / -name php-pear-crypt*
yum list installed | grep php
rpm -qa | grep php-*
```

But no results. How can it be? How to find this package? Where is this error from?

Comment: sounds like a pear package, so try `pear list-packages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the error message.

```
Error: Package: php-pear-crypt-gpg-1.6.3-1.el7.remi.noarch (remi)
           Requires: gnupg < 2
```

I thought i need to install gnupg for php-pear-crypt-gpg, but no, vice-versa i needed to install `php-pear-crypt-gpg` for gnupg1.

Sorry for my linux novice experience. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I cannot reproduce:

```
# yum install --enablerepo=remi php-pear-crypt-gpg
...
Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                           Version                                          Repository                               Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pear-crypt-gpg                                   noarch                         1.6.3-1.el7.remi                                 remi                                    317 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gnupg1                                               x86_64                         1.4.20-1.el7.remi                                remi                                    1.3 M
 php-mbstring                                         x86_64                         7.2.16~RC1-2.el7.remi                            remi-php72-test                         623 k
 php-pear-Console-CommandLine                         noarch                         1.2.2-1.el7.remi                                 remi                                     55 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 2.3 M
Installed size: 9.8 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

> The remaining transaction had 593 elements left to run

I looks like your RPM/YUM database is in a very bad state,
you have to finish pending transaction, and fix it.